# Create bookmarks in Chrome mobile browser. (Galaxy s4)

Tags: samsung, samsung-galaxy-s-4

All over the internet it says there is a five pointed star to the right of the URL in omni bar. This is not the case with the version of Chrome packaged with the Samsung Galaxy S4. How can I create a bookmark?

[image: Samsung Galaxy S4 displaying google chrome]

There's only one button. The tab button.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hit the menu button (bottom left of the phone) and then click on the star (which will be at the top right of the dialog which appears).

The star is only to the right of the URL on the omni bar on the desktop version of Chrome.

Comment: Ahh yes. Used to an iphone see, where everything is on the screen. Thanks

Comment: I appreciate the answers, but my new Samsung core will not bookmark as per the recommendation as it deletes the url I want when I hit the menu button as suggested. Anyone have another answer ? thanks

Comment: @NeilD Never heard of the "Samsung Core" but if you're using the latest Chrome on your Android phone, drag the page down a little, revealing the URL, then click the 3 dots (top right of the screen on my phone), then click on the star icon to bookmark.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the page that you want to bookmark. Next, click on the left option button on your phone itself. On the very top of the menu that pops up, you will see a star.  Click on it and follow the prompts.

Answer (score -1):

Use the bookmark button that is marked in this picture:

[image]

Comment: That's not Chrome!